# BASH deleting HTML tags from the text file

Tags: bash, sed

I need to filter out all HTML tags from the text file (could be any sequence between <...>)

I came up with this command: `cat my_file | sed 's/<[^>]*>//'`, but it olny delets first tag in the line. How do I delete all the tags? Is the problem with the regular expression?

Comment: You could use a tool like xml starlet to extract just the text. If your HTML is formed in such a way that it is also compatible with XML this should work.

Comment: I need to use `sed` command in bash. this is a task for school

Comment: Hi Pyzololo, is your question _How to remove the HTML tags from a file?_ or is your question _How can I tell sed to do more then one substitution?_

Answer (score 2):

From the `sed` manual:

> The `s` command can be followed by zero or more of the following flags:
>
> ```
>     g
> ```
>
> Apply the replacement to *all* matches to the regexp, not just the *first*.

So

```
 cat my_file | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

Comment: UUOC: better `sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' my_file`.

Comment: @WalterA Agreed but one thing at a time — the OP's question was not how to accomplish the overall goal but merely why the regex was being applied only to the first occurrence of the pattern in the target.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to remove all tags and get only text between them. Use, html2text or pup 'text{}'
https://github.com/ericchiang/pup
http://www.mbayer.de/html2text/
There are other tools like xidel, xmlstarlet too.